# How to add NFS options flag to anaconda?

Tags: fedora, rhel, nfs, kickstart, installer-anaconda

These options work for Kickstart to load the install tree from NFS:
The Fedora [Kickstart documentation](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#install) states

```
nfs --server=nfsserver.example.com --dir=/tmp/install-tree --opts="username=u1,password=p1"
```

The [RedHat6 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/sn-automating-installation.html) install guide does not mention the options flag but they are mentioned in the [Fedora guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda_Boot_Options?rd=Anaconda/Options):

```
ks=nfs[:options]:<server>:<path>
```

How to add nfs options parameter to Anaconda in RHEL6.x?

Answer (score 1):

You pass NFS options to RHEL 6's kickstart process the same way you do in Fedora. See https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html for details.

Comment: I have linked to the same document as you, why do you think that your answer would help me?

Comment: You linked to https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/sn-automating-installation.html which is not the same document. The document I linked to specifically calls out the <code>--opts=</code> parameter to the <code>nfs</code> option for the <code>install</code> directive. Thus, I think my answer is helpful because it provides a direct response to your query from official Red Hat documentation.

Comment: Its a different section within the same document. I saw the `--opts` flag but that is placed inside the KS file to load the install tree. I was wondering if the ":options" flag is supported on RHEL6.x? `ks=nfs[:options]:<server>:<path>`

Comment: Ok. I was reading the question wrong. However, looking through the source code in the anaconda package, it looks like the :options flag is supported. In /usr/lib/anaconda/ituil.py, which I believe handles the boot: prompt option processing, the parseNfsUrl() routine processes either (options, host, path) or (host, path) dependinf on the split of the url passed.

Comment: Thanks for checking, however I get `Error downloading kickstart file` dialog. `nfs:username=xx,password=psw://server:/path/foo.ks` I checked and I was able to map the share using `mount` command.